# dense subset of the set of all $\mathbb{F}$-adapted process on the interval $[t,T]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $(W_t)_{t\geq0}$ a standard Brownian motion on this space. The filtration generated by the Brownian motion is denoted by $$\mathcal{F}_t:=\sigma\{W_u,0\leq u\leq t\}\vee\mathcal{N},\ 
\mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0},$$where $\mathcal{N}$ is the collection of null sets. Moreover, for some fixed $s\geq0$,
$$\mathcal{F}_t^s:=\sigma\{W_{s+u}-W_s,0\leq u\leq t\}\vee\mathcal{N},\ 
\mathbb{F}^s=\{\mathcal{F}_t^s\}_{t\geq0}.$$ Denote by $\mathcal{A}_{t,T}^\Gamma$ the collection of all $\Gamma$-valued $\mathbb{F}$-adapted process on the interval $[t,T].$ How to prove that $$\{\theta_s=\sum_{j=1}^NI_{A_j}\theta_s^j|\{A_j\}_{j=1}^N\ is\ an\ \mathcal{F}_t\ partition\ of\ \Omega, \theta^j\in \mathcal{A}_{t,T}^\Gamma\ is\ \mathbb{F}^t-adapted\}$$ is dense in $\mathcal{A}_{t,T}^\Gamma$? Thanks!

Comment: According to the statement, for $A\in\mathcal{F}_t$, $\theta_s(\omega):=1_A(\omega)$ is in the dense set of $\mathcal{A}_{t,T}^\Gamma$ and is $\mathbb{F}$-adpated.